Xano realtime SDK disconnects
I am using Xano realtime SDK in my react-native expo application. The SDK setup is done like this.
import 'react-native-url-polyfill'

import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import { XanoClient, XanoSessionStorage } from '@xano/js-sdk';
import * as GlobalVariables from '../config/GlobalVariableContext';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const XanoContext = createContext();
export function Xano({
    children
}) {

    const setGlobalVariableValue = GlobalVariables.useSetValue();
    const Constants = GlobalVariables.useValues();

    const [xano, setXano] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS == 'web') return
        const xano = new XanoClient({
            instanceBaseUrl: Constants["XANO_BASE_URL"],
            storage: AsyncStorage,
            realtimeConnectionHash: Constants["XANO_REALTIME_CONN_HASH"],
        });

        setXano(xano)[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ecjtPMvI.png)
    }, [])


    // set realtime token
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('token ', Constants['AUTH_TOKEN'])
        if (Constants['AUTH_TOKEN'] && xano) {
            const token = Constants['AUTH_TOKEN'].split(' ')[1]
            // console.log('setting token ', token)
            xano.setRealtimeAuthToken(token)


            console.log('realtime token', xano.hasRealtimeAuthToken());
        }

    }, [Constants['AUTH_TOKEN'], xano])




    const value = {
        xano
    }


    return (
        <XanoContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </XanoContext.Provider>
    )

}



The sdk sometime disconnects. How can I reconnect and when it does that. Also the realtime SDK doesn't work in the PWA. I am getting this error.
I tried to find out a way to reconnect to sdk but the doc doesn't provide any clue about how to do that.
